# Count min and max from a field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table 1 like this:

```
number     p     uc_id     date
3         1        g        24/09/2015
4         0        g        24/09/2015
5         1        g        24/09/2015
5         1        f        25/09/2015
3         0        f        25/09/2015
5         1        g        26/09/2015
```

And a table 2 like:

```
id       name
g        Magic
f        Blue
```

I want that sql query returns something like

```
name      min     max
Magic     1       2
Blue      1       1
```

My query i have done something like date but i can't retrive the min and max

```
Select 
    p.date, 
    uc.name, 
    min((Select 
         uc.name, 
         count(p.p) 
         from table1 p, table2 uc 
         where p.p = 1 and uc.id = p.uc_id 
         group by uc.name, p.date)) as 'Min', 
    max((Select uc.name, 
         count(p.p) 
         from table1 p, table2 uc 
         where p.p=1 and uc.id = p.uc_id 
         group by uc.name, p.date)) as 'Max' 
From table1 p, table2 uc
Where uc.id = p.uc_id
group by uc.name
```

I want to count the column p where p=1 and group by them by date and for each date i want to retrive the min and max of the count done prevously. Also showing the name in the other table.

Comment: what is your return query logic, what is min / max ?

Comment: `Min when p=0 and Max when p=1`????why Max for magic is 2 not 3??

Comment: One error is you use alias `p` in your `inner select` and `outer select`

Comment: Basically i want to retrive the max and min value from p ...but only count where p=1 i want to see in one date count how many 1 there are in each day and tell the min and max of them

Comment: still need more information. group by date or by name? Your sample say `max Magic` is equal to 2 but not `p = 2` in that sample

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I want a count where table2.p=1 from each date and then from each date tell the min count of table1.p and the max count of table1.p.

Comment: Because the date

`number     p     uc_id     date
3               1        g        24/09/2015
4               0        g        24/09/2015
5               1        g        24/09/2015`

theres the max g can have of p = 2

in:
`5         1        g        26/09/2015`

it's only max 1 beacuse of the day that has 1

Comment: So your result should include date or not?

Comment: Also for your formula min and max are the same value `Count(p=1)`

Comment: Yes, should count as the date but it's not important to show

Comment: i'm not fluent in sql, that's why i'm asking help

Comment: Its ok if you arent fluent in sql, But you could put a litle more effort in describe the problem

Comment: I edited the topic to explain what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0af8b/1)

Create a subquery with the total count name by date.

```
SELECT name, min(nCount) cMin, max(nCount) cMax
FROM (Select 
          uc.name,
          p.date, 
          count(p) as nCount
      From table1 p, table2 uc
      Where uc.id = p.uc_id
      and   p = 1 
      group by uc.name, p.date) nameCount
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: I use MS SQL 2014, let me know if you have a diferent RDBMS. In the fiddle you could select the text inside the `nameCount` to see the partial result.

Comment: I'm using mysql, with its not supported there ... but yes it's this that i need

Comment: I update to MySql. Remember next time include that information in your question.

Comment: Thanks it's it :D Muchas Gracias !